# integer division gives incorrect result

Tags: z3

I try to check satisfiability of `x div y == 2` and `x / y == 2` but got incorrect results both times.  Looks like Z3 doesn't support these yet ?

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)

(assert (=  (div x y ) 2))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)

sat
(model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    0)
  (define-fun x () Int
    38)
)



(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)

(assert (=  (/ x y ) 2))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)

sat
(model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    0)
  (define-fun x () Int
    1)
)
```

Comment: Please format your code according to [these instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Integer division is supported, see: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/Ints.smt2

Real division is also supported (from here: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/Reals.smt2), the issue with division by zero you mention is covered:
"Since in SMT-LIB logic all function symbols are interpreted as total functions, terms of the form (/ t 0) *are* meaningful in every  instance of Reals. However, the declaration imposes no constraints on their value. This means in particular that 
  - for every instance theory T and
  - for every closed terms t1 and t2 of sort Real, 
there is a model of T that satisfies (= t1 (/ t2 0))."

You should add an assertion that the divisor is not equal to zero.

`(assert (not (= y 0)))`

Here's the example (rise4fun link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/IUDE ):

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)

(assert (not (= y 0)))

(push)
(assert (=  (div x y ) 2))
(check-sat)
(get-model) ; gives x = 2, y = 1
(pop)

(push)
(assert (=  (/ x y ) 2))
(check-sat)
(get-model) ; gives x = -2, y = -1
(pop)
```